# Error: EISDIR: File is a directory., '/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins' (CodeSandbox / Bootstrap / VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, codesandbox

I'm a bit new to all of those web techs (CodeSandbox, Bootstrap and VueJS) but I learn fast. After doing a lot of research, I wanted to start my web platform project with [this project template](https://flatlogic.com/templates/sing-app-vue-dashboard) to have a good base and a good structure but I'm stuck with this error :

> Cannot find module 'bootstrap/scss/mixins' from '/src/styles'

And when I look in the file containing the "import" directive :

> Error: Error: EISDIR: File is a directory., '/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins'
> on line 10:9 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
> from line 10:2 of /stdin
> >> @import "mixins";

I understand that "mixins" is a directory, okay, but it's the bootstrap code man... I cannot change it on codesandbox and after checking on [bootstrap github's repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap), it seems normal that "mixins" is a directory.

You can check the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-bohr-jp804) (no changes made, project just imported, modules not updated, I tried but it changed nothing). The file containing all import directives is src/styles/themes.scss [direct link](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-bohr-jp804?file=/src/styles/theme.scss).

Thanks by advance for your help ! :)